# Difficulty with the chain rule: unable to confirm that the sum $\frac {dx^u} {dt} \frac {d\vec V} {dx^u}$ equals $\frac {d\vec V} {dt}$

Tags: tensors, chain-rule

My book `Tensors made easy` by Giancarlo Bernacci makes the following claim:

$\frac {D \vec V} {d \tau}$ is referred to as the *covariant derivative along a line* ... It can be expressed as:

$\frac {D V^b} {d \tau} := U^a \nabla_a V^b = U^a (\frac {\partial V^b} {\partial x^a} + \Gamma _{a \lambda} ^b V^\lambda) = \frac {d V^b} {d x^a} \frac {d x^a} {d \tau} + \Gamma _{a \lambda} ^b V^\lambda U^a = \frac {d V^b} {d \tau} + \Gamma _{a \lambda} ^b V^\lambda U^a$

End quote.

Here the covariant derivative of $\vec V$ is being taken along a line parameterized as $x^a = x^a(\tau)$ with tangent $\vec U = \frac {d x^a} {d \tau} \vec e_a$.

What I don't understand is how it is that the chain rule gives $\frac {d V^b} {d x^a} \frac {d x^a} {d \tau} = \frac {d V^b} {d \tau}$ since the LHS is a sum over the abstract index $a$ and the RHS appears to be obtained by canceling abstract indices.

(My naive expectation would be that the sum expands as follows: $\frac {d V^b} {d x^a} \frac {d x^a} {d \tau} = \frac {d V^b} {d x^1} \frac {d x^1} {d \tau} + ... + \frac {d V^b} {d x^n} \frac {d x^n} {d \tau} = n \frac {d V^b} {d \tau} $ which differs by a factor of $n$ from what the book claims)

---

That should be all that is needed to explain to me how the book's definition actually works and how I am misunderstanding it.  However, here is some more information that may come in useful.  I'm doing problem 38:

A particle follows a helical path on the surface of a cylinder parameterized as:

$l = \begin{cases} x = \rho \space cos \space \omega t \\
y = \rho \space sin \space \omega t \\
z = h t
\end{cases}$

Compute:

a) the vector tangent to the path

b) the derivative along the line of the tangent vector itself

My answer to a) is

$\vec T = (\frac {d x} {d t}, \frac {d y} {d t}, \frac {d z} {d t}) = (-\rho \omega \space sin \space \omega t, \rho \omega \space cos \space \omega t, h)$

My answer to b) is

$\frac {d \vec T} {d t} = <\tilde\nabla \vec T, \vec T> = \nabla _\vec T \vec T \rightarrow ^{comp} T^a \nabla_a T^b = T^a \partial_a T^b$

(last equality holds because $\Gamma$ are all zero in the standard Euclidean basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$)

With $b=x$ we have $T^a \nabla_a T^x = T^x \partial_x T^x + T^y \partial_y T^x + T^z \partial_z T^x$

Now $\partial_x T^x = - \partial_x \rho \omega \space sin \space \omega t$

$= - \partial_x (\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \rho \omega \space sin \space \omega t$ (using the identity that $\rho = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$)

$= - \omega \space cos \space \omega t \space sin \space \omega t$ (differentiating with respect to $x$ and substituting again)

Likewise $\partial_y T^x = -\omega \space sin^2 \space \omega t$

And $\partial_z T^x = 0$

With that we can find the $x$ coordinate of the derivative along the line of $\vec T$

$T^x \partial_x T^x + T^y \partial_y T^x + T^z \partial_z T^x = \rho \omega^2 \space cos \space \omega t \space sin^2 \space \omega t - \rho \omega^2 \space cos \space \omega t \space sin^2 \space \omega t = 0$

The correct $x$ coordinate is $-\rho \omega^2 \space cos \space \omega t$.  The two ways of solving the problem (expanding and summing over abstract indices v.s. canceling them via the chain rule) should yield the same result, but they do not.  What gives?

Comment: The problem you have in the title *is* the chain rule. Nothing more, nothing less. The chain rule for a function of many variables gives a sum. For example $\frac{df(x(t)),y(t))}{dt} = \frac{df}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{df}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt}$. You seem to believe that the right hand side should be equal to $2 \frac{df}{dt}$ ("which differs by a factor of  from what the book claims"), but that is incorrect.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I must be having some problem with indices in problem 38 below.

Comment: I figured out what went wrong with problem 38, long story short I did it all wrong.

Comment: @Winther If you want to copy paste that into an answer, I'll accept it.